# Make parent menu link clickable multiple times

Tags: drop-down-menu, drupal-7, parent-child

I've tried to google my way to a solution for a while now but I haven't found something that deals with the same problem yet.

I'm using drupal 7 and I'm trying to make the parent item (lets say "About" as the parent) clickable again after being directed to this page. The "About" tab has two children; "Contact us" and "Support us". If I go from any other page on the site I can click "About", but after that it's not possible to get back to the main parent ("About") without leaving the "About" page (or its children).

The description is kind of confusing, so let me try to explain it from the users perspective:
I go from "Home" -> "About" (that has some content) -> "Contact us" (subitem to "about"). Now I want to get back to "About" which is not possible (dropdown menu with "Contact Us" and "Support Us" appears as clickable, but "About" is not).

The site we're using has a Stanford University Theme, which might be the problem because on my own site (with other themes such as "Business" and "Responsive Business") I don't have this problem.

Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm kinda new into this.

Comment: Please post your work-in-progress code implementation.

Comment: Can you inspect the parent menu link (About) with devtools (eg Chrome dvetools) to see which element comes over it and disallows clicking? Except if there is no link so you have to find why it's being removed.

Comment: @JAL Sorry, I don't really know what that means.

Comment: @theodorosploumis does this help: `<li class="expanded active-trail dropdown"><a href="/about" id="about" class="active-trail dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">About <span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li class="first leaf active-trail active"><a href="/about/contact-information" class="active-trail active">Contact Us</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/about/support-us">Support Us</a></li>
</ul></li> `?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap theme or something related for the menu?